# What are the conditions when a 2D memory instantiated in Verilog is mapped to BRAM by ISE?

Tags: verilog, xilinx-ise

Upon searching in multiple forums, I did not find a comprehensive answer.

I would like to understand, when does `[PARAM1:0] ram [PARAM2:0]` inferred as a Block RAM by the ISE synthesizer and when it is not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This list of conditions might be incomplete:

- **Size**
  If the memory is to small, ISE will use a distibuted RAM (LUT-RAM) instead of a BlockRAM. The size / area of your memory must be mapable to a single or group of BlockRAMs. A single BlockRAMs can have 8,9,16,18,32,36,64,72 bits per data port. Other sizes are possible if the number of memory lines matches.
- **Ports**
  BlockRAM supports:

  - single-port (SP),
  - simple-dual-port (SDP),
  - enhanced-simple-dual-port (ESDP) and
  - true-dual-port (TDP)

  memories. Combinations with one write port and n read ports a also possible.
- **Reset**
  BlockRAMs don't support resets. So if you memory can be reset, if can be inferred as BRAM.
- **ClockEnable (CE), Write-Enable (WE), Byte-Write-Enable (BWE)**
  BlockRAMs support CE and WE, but usually no BWE.
- **Timing**
  The memory must be synchronously written and either synchronously read or asynchronously read with from a registered address.
- **Output Registers (OUT_REG)**
  Output registers are optional, but improve the overall timing. The synthesizer might move the OUT_REG from logic into the BlockRAM, which has embedded output registers.

Our open-source library PoC contains 4 possible [on-chip RAM](https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC/tree/master/src/mem/ocram) implementations written in generic VHDL code, which can be mapped to Xilinx BlockRAMs. I assume you can read and understand these VHDL snippets, to translate it into Verilog code :). Alternatively, Xilinx offers a [synthesis guide](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx14_7/sim.pdf#page=73) (UG 626, v14.4, p. 73)), which lists VHDL and Verilog design patterns of synthesizable code.